# URI for a custom media-type?

Tags: pdf, uri, rdf, media-type

I need to describe in RDF documents that are electronically signed PDFs versus documents that are normal PDFs. The [list of IANA media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) only contains [`application/pdf`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/pdf) media type.

What is the good practice to use a custom URI to identify electronically signed PDF from a normal PDF?

I am reading that a new media-type could be defined starting with `x-`; can I simply define `http://example.com/media-type/application/x-signed-pdf` and use this URI as a value for a `dcterms:format` (or `myontology:mediaType`) property in RDF?

Comment: @jschnasse : I will not accept your answer since I already described and validated another answer describing an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually chose to :

1. Have 2 distinct metadata properties : the "true" media-type, relying only on IANA-registered media types, and an application-specific "media-type";
2. For the "true" media type we rely exclusively on registered IANA values, and for the  "custom" type we define our own list of URIs as possible values;

So, we can rely on the "true" media-type property to do proper content negociation, and use the "custom" property for application-specific behavior.

Comment: Could you add an example? From what you describe, I understood that you're doing something like `<s> <trueMediaTyp> "application/json"` and `<s> <customMediaType> <customURI>` ? So, each resource has two different properties with two different types to express the media type?

Comment: @jschnasse : exactly. We are separating the actual file-format (IANA) from the more business-oriented format. The file format is pure IANA, the business-oriented format typically refers to a specific XML schema, or says "scanned PDF" vs "electronically signed PDF"

Answer (score 1):

**1.** I wouldn't use a URI at all. Just define a '[vendor](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.2)' or '[personal](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.3)' media type like...

```
application/vnd.yourcompany.signed-pdf
application/prs.yourapp.signed-pdf
```

...and store it as literal with dc elements. http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/format

```
".... Recommended best practice is to use a controlled vocabulary such as
the list of Internet Media Types [MIME]."
```

**2.** If you need a URI based approach you could use IANA URLs for registered media types like:

```
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/pdf
```

I assume that `vnd` media types will also get a similar URI at IANA.

**3.** Also See this discussion on ["Cool" Linked Data URIs for all IANA mediatypes?](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/media-types/current/msg00685.html)

> How to describe mediatypes in RDF is still a bit unclear, it is
> however common to use Dublin Core's "format" property, although there
> are two approaches:

http://example.com/image.png dc:format "text/html"

> 

No links to follow here.. and dc:format also allows any kind of format
literals like "VHS" and "Polaroid". Easy to use, though.

> 

The dcterms:format property [7] is more suited as it goes to a
resource, but is a bit cumbersome to describe correctly as an IANA
type, see [4] ...

Comment: I would definitely use a URI. As you quote, the "use of a controlled vocabulary" does not fit well with using a free-text literal.

Comment: Registering or using a "vendor" media type looks like a good idea.